# What does querySelector() do when not called on the document?

Tags: javascript

In the [MDN template docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) I saw code as  `clone.querySelectorAll("td");`, so out of curiosity I wrote JS code snippet as `document.querySelector(".para").append(" hello");h5.querySelector(".para").append(" world")` to try to append 'world' to 'hello', but got an error.

Please explain the concept of a non-document(dot)querySelector style and its usage to rectify my error

```js
h5=document.createElement('h5');
h5.textContent= "text updated";
h5.className= "first";
document.querySelector(".para").append(" hello");//works
h5.querySelector(".para").append(" world");//console log error of value null meaning nothing selected
```

```html
<p class="para"> Test: </p>
```

Comment: It just restricts matching the selector to descendants of `h5`, rather than searching the entire DOM.

Comment: [The `querySelector()` method of an Element returns the first element that is a descendant of the given Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

Comment: Please do not put "edit" at the top of your question. If you want to make adjustments, please make sure that the question represents its current state. If the edit part was an answer then add it below in the answer space with a proper explanation.

Comment: @Barmar please repost your alternative answer but without the innerHTML? because as per MDN {https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML} there is a security issue if I understood right

Comment: The security risk is only if you get the HTML from an untrusted source, it can cause XSS. There's no problem with a simple string constant used for a demo. I can't fit the longer version in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `querySelector()` on an element restricts the search to the element's descendants, rather than searching the entire DOM.

You need to insert a `<p class="para">` inside the `<h5>` so it will be found. And if you want to see the results, you need to append `h5` to the document.

```js
let h5=document.createElement('h5');
let p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = 'Test2:';
p.classList.add('para');
h5.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(h5);
h5.className= "first";
document.querySelector(".para").append(" hello");//works
h5.querySelector(".para").append(" world");
```

```html
<p class="para"> Test: </p>
```